Cannot persist entity
I have been getting this exception. What would be the best way to implement versioning in an entity so that I can persist my entity? I would like to avoid unnecessary setters if possible
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot set property version because no setter, no wither and it's not part of the persistence constructor public com.ezycorp.eve.domain.Merchant(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)

This is my entity
@Table("merchant")
public class Merchant {

    @Id
    private final MerchantId id;

    private final String name;

    private final MerchantKeyId merchantKeyId;

    private final String username;

    private final String password;

    private final String webhookUrl;

    @Version
    private final int version=0;


    @PersistenceCreator
    public Merchant(String id, String name, Integer merchantKeyId, String username, String password, String webhookUrl) {
        this.id = new MerchantId(id);
        this.name = name;
        this.merchantKeyId = new MerchantKeyId(merchantKeyId);
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.webhookUrl = webhookUrl;
    }
}

...omitted getters


Looks like your entity is immutable. Why d you even need version? Anyway you either treat it as all your other fields and add it to constructor parameters, or provide setter. BTW you could learn that by reading error you provided.

The error message pretty much tells you your options:

no setter: create a setter. Actually just making version package private (no modifier) and not final is sufficient

no wither: create a "wither",
Merchant withVersion(int version){
    Merchant newMerchant = ... // create a new instance with the new version
    return newMerchant;
}


not part of the persistence constructor public com.ezycorp.eve.domain.Merchant(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String): Create a constructor that includes the version. Either by adding it to the parameter list or by creating a separate constructor. In the later case you'll need to annotate that with @PersistenceCreator



thank you kind sir
